# Program to set up Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, automation

I switch laptops frequently (since I like to try everything).
I have made a folder, what I download from Mega, what includes installation files of all programs I use or might use. I install lots of them at a time, but it would be nice it is automated. That's not the big part.

The main problem is to rename the pc, set up anydesk, mega sync folders, log in to 3 chrome users, install few games and software on Steam. They can be all different programs, since I can script to run them all at once. They can be paid programs (total <20$/€).

Comment: Something like Chocolatey can automate downloading and installing lots of programs, however it doesn't handle any other configuration tasks. Writing a custom script for those could be a solution, I doubt there is any prebuilt software to handle this very particular case.